# Using stationary camera to track a moving object

Tags: camera, computer-vision, robotics, camera-calibration, autonomy

I am new to computer vision, and need some advice on where to start.

I am looking to track a moving robot using a stationary, external camera positioned on the ceiling. The robot should complete an obstacle course autonomously using feedback from the camera. In essence, I am looking to develop a "map" of where the robot currently is, which the robot would interpret and decide which direction it should go.

I have looked through many scholarly articles on the subject, but most research seems to be focused on cameras onboard the robot. I am assuming that using a stationary camera would be easier to track motion, and was looking for any advice on where to begin and the general steps I need to take (ex. camera-calibration, image processing, relay signal to robot, etc).

Thanks a ton!

Comment: What technology(?) are you planning on use to develop your project? I have done something similar (but yeah, with the camera attached to the robot) in the past working with Arduino and raw C. Also explain a little bit more what is it that you need, as it seems unclear

Comment: The question is very vague. Can you control the environment and the robot's appearance and are free to choose your technology? Is the obstacle course small enough (or the ceiling high enough) that one single camera's view will encompass it all - given the lens you are thinking to use and the sensor's resolution? Note that if the robot has an unobstructed view of the ceiling (as it should be, since you plan to track from the ceiling), a robot-mounted camera may yield an easier and more robust solution, by detecting and locating a known pattern painted on the ceiling

Answer (score 0):

As @Callari mentioned your question is not so clear. But I would assume two things for writing my answer: (1) Your environment is static, (2) Obstacles are also static.

You need to create a map of your environment from the camera. Use [this](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3812593/) kind of an approach to calculate the positions of different obstacles with respect to some reference point.

Once you have the positions of obstacles you need to do the [mapping](http://forums.trossenrobotics.com/tutorials/introduction-129/an-introduction-to-mapping-and-localization-3274/) of your environment. If you have a metric map then it's nothing but an occupancy grid. This map has to be with your robot and if it starts from the same reference location, initialize your robot with some start_location and start_orientation. Use [Dead Reckoning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_reckoning) for localization and keep updating position and orientation of your robot as it move through.

Then you need to do the path planning for your robot. You can use [A-Star](http://wiki.gamegardens.com/Path_Finding_Tutorial) algorithm to find a path for your robot. After reaching the goal point do the path planning again.

In case of dynamic obstacles, iteratively find positions of obstacles from camera and do the path planning. I am new to the subject but have gathered some information lately, due to my interest in robotics.